# Building Android from source on Lynx and Oneiric but reaches their "end-of-life". What now?

Tags: android, ubuntu-10.04, android-source, ubuntu-11.10

[Ubuntu 10.04](http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2013/05/10/ubuntu-10-04-lucid-lynx-desktop-end-of-life-reached-on-may-9-2013/) and [11.10](http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2013/05/10/ubuntu-11-10-oneiric-ocelot-end-of-life-reached-on-may-9-2013/) reached their **end-of-life** last May 09 2013, what happens if I'm going to build android from source with these platforms?  Does it affect the build process?

In the [Initializing Build Environment](http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html#installing-required-packages-ubuntu-1204) site, building on Ubuntu 12.04 is currently only experimentally supported and is not guaranteed to work other than master.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily use Ubuntu 12.04 for all variants of Android. The only thing you need is to download the latest versions of the required version. Personally, I use Ubuntu 12.04 for developing Android 2.3.4. You can look into [this](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-building/BcPSFFg3j48/WJ9NH7IiQyEJ) thread for more information.